# What collation does MySQL use by default for ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, collation

These queries both give the result I expect:

```
SELECT sex
FROM ponies
ORDER BY sex COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ASC

SELECT sex
FROM ponies
ORDER BY CONVERT(sex USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_general_ci ASC

| f |
| f |
| m |
| m |
+---+
```

But this query gives a different result:

```
SELECT sex FROM ponies ORDER BY sex ASC

| m |
| m |
| f |
| f |
+---+
```

Here's the configuration:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation\_%'

| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

The table collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`.

MySQL server is 5.5.16.

Comment: Please add the `create table` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour can be observed when `sex` is an `ENUM` in which case it is usually sorted by the numerical position in the `ENUM` definition. Only when a collation is explicitly given an it is sorted in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

### Table Collations

Collation defaults are stored on a table-by-table basis. There is a server-set default, but that is applied to the table at the time it is created.

To find the collation for a specific table, run this query:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'ponies'\G
```

You should see output like this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: ponies
         Engine: MyISAM
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Fixed
           Rows: 8
 Avg_row_length: 20
    Data_length: 160
Max_data_length: 5629499534213119
   Index_length: 1024
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2012-02-27 10:16:25
    Update_time: 2012-02-27 10:17:40
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And you can see the `Collation` setting in that result.

### Column collations

You can also override collation settings on particular columns within a table. A create table statement like this would create a `latin1_swedish_ci` table, with a `utf8_polish_ci` column:

```
CREATE TABLE ponies (
    sex CHAR(1) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci
) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

The best way to view the results of this is like this:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ponies;
```

Output:

```
+-------+---------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type    | Collation      | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+---------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| sex   | char(1) | utf8_polish_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------+---------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: As I wrote, the table collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`, so why is there a difference between `ORDER BY sex COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ASC` and `ORDER BY sex ASC`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that last line there; I thought you were looking at the server configuration rather than the table configuration

Comment: Try the `SHOW FULL COLUMNS` query to see if that gives you any more relevant information.

Comment: Nothing special, collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`. And I freshly created the database a moment ago anyway. BTW, can you reproduce my observation?

Comment: Argh, I forgot it's an ENUM. That explains everything. Sorry. :(

Comment: And I actually had http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html#c8409 on screen in another tab, and totally missed it. Glad you caught that, though.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sorting-rows.html) says it uses a case insensitive character comparison by default.  I don't see why you are not getting that result though.

The documentation also suggests using the `binary` qualifier for case sensitive comparison.  I wonder if that would affect your result?:

```
SELECT sex FROM ponies ORDER BY BINARY sex ASC
```

Comment: Yes, that also gives the expected result. So what strange sort order (case-insensitive or not) is it that puts *m* before *f*? (Yes, my table values are all lowercase.)

Comment: Is it possible that one or the other of the field values are an extended UTF representation (not ASCII) for either `m` or `f`?

Comment: `SELECT HEX(sex) FROM ponies` shows `66` and `6D`, `ORDER BY sex ASC` sorts `6D`before `66`.

Comment: Argh, I forgot it's an ENUM. That explains everything. Sorry. :(